# Distinct Results MSSQL Group By?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm not MSSQL pro, in fact it frustrates me the "Microsoft Way" of doing some things, but 
hey, enough of a rant. 
I have the need to run a very simple query, in Mysql its very simple but in MSSQL I can not achieve what I want.

I have 1 table, the table contains usernames and passwords and a year code, however some accounts are duplicated and I need to be able to pull the latest result for all students

**Table**

```
username__________password____________yearcode
112211------------dgsvdhsa------------11/12
112211------------dsgvrrhb------------12/13
234543------------36%Sldof------------11/12
344321------------sDDdesSs------------11/12
234543------------plOKjwDS------------12/13
```

**Desired Output**

```
username__________password____________yearcode
112211------------dsgvrrhb------------12/13
344321------------sDDdesSs------------11/12
234543------------plOKjwDS------------12/13
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated, I have tried grouping by Username and I get aggregate function errors. I have tried Distinct and I get not the desired  results.

Thank you for your help, below is the final solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_CODE ORDER BY SessionCode DESC) rnum
    FROM table.dbo.Students t
    WHERE t.FORENAME LIKE '%$user%' OR t.SURNAME LIKE '%$user%' OR t.PERSON_CODE LIKE '%$user%'
) q
```

WHERE rnum = 1

Comment: Post the queries that you have tried. That will help people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```sql
SELECT username, password, yearcode
  FROM
(
  SELECT t.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY yearcode DESC) rnum
    FROM table1 t
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
 ORDER BY username;
```

or an old-school way without windowing functions

```sql
SELECT t.username, t.password, t.yearcode
  FROM 
(
  SELECT username, MAX(yearcode) yearcode
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY username
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.username = t.username
   AND q.yearcode = t.yearcode
 ORDER BY username;
```

Output:

```
| USERNAME | PASSWORD | YEARCODE |
|----------|----------|----------|
|   112211 | dsgvrrhb |    12/13 |
|   234543 | plOKjwDS |    12/13 |
|   344321 | sDDdesSs |    11/12 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb130/5)** demo

Comment: This is perfect, I will edit my post to show the full query with my where clauses. But your great. I don't understand why you would select and select again. Could you explain this? - Being a PHP developer Im so used to doing all my dataset processing PHP side rather than server side.

Comment: In the inner select we get row number for each username ordered descending by year code. This way will get a row number = 1 for all latest records per user. Then in the outer select we filter out all records that are not equal to 1 effectively leaving only latest records. Analytic windowing functions are very fast and powerful.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense to me now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the entries for the latest `yearcode`.

In plain SQL I would do something like this:

```
select * from table t1 where yearcode =  
   (select max(yearcode) from table t2 where t1.username = t2.username );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this query, it will work for your condition,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(username),password,yearcode
FROM Table1 t;
```

Comment: It will return all the rows.

Comment: Im sure I have tried this before and it does not return the desired results. But Peterm managed to give the solution thank you though Shivam .

Comment: hey but up my answer somebody put one down to it.